# Overriding Flask Extensions Classes

Tags: flask, flask-kvsession

What is the preferred method of overriding a Flask Extension's Class inside your app.

e.g.

Using FlaskKvSession: https://github.com/mbr/flask-kvsession/blob/master/flaskext/kvsession.py

How would your override SessionID(object):**init**(self, id, created=None): in your app, without monkey patching the core extension.